# How is inference performed in the RNN "many-to-one" architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I'm looking at the diagram for the "many-to-one" architecture [here](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/teaching/cs-230/cheatsheet-recurrent-neural-networks) and
it looks like in the training phase there would be weights trained across activations between timesteps $W_{aa}$, between inputs and activations $W_{ax}$ and between activations and outputs ${W_{ya}}$.

So assuming that variable length sequences will be used at prediction time, how is it known when the end of the sequence is reached and the final ${W_{ya}}$ weights need to be applied to get the final predicted output?  Is it something like

```
if is_final_timestep: apply W_{ya} else: apply W_{aa}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it a little confused. I'm not sure my take is totally correct, but maybe it helps:

We can do a loop over the input time-steps, in each step applying W_aa and W_ax as you said. Then once the loop is done we take the final hidden state and apply W_ya.